# Do camera libraries exist for XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Do libraries of different cameras exist for XNA? I've searched around and found lots of different camera classes with different interfaces (or no defined interface at all) but no common interface with standard camera definitions.

I feel that there must be something that I'm missing, it seems like such a crucial aspect of any game that there must be a good reason for the lack of camera libraries.

Comment: What is a "standard camera definition"?

Comment: Apologies, I don't think I was being clear. I'm a complete 3d game and XNA nub, so I have no idea what standard camera definitions could be. However, I'm confused that there don't appear to be any. It would appear (from a very naive first look) as though some interface with a means of updating the camera, getting a View matrix and a Projection matrix would be feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little bit ambiguous. So I'll do my best to explain how to do cameras in XNA.

Basically a camera is just a Matrix (as you seem to already know), or collection of matrices. Conventionally you have a View matrix (position the camera in the world) and a Project matrix (project the 3D points of the world onto the 2D viewport).

Because cameras are as simple as this - there is really no need for some kind of comprehensive camera library. It is generally easier for a game to "hard code" a simple camera class that fulfils the functionality required by that game, than to try and solve the exponentially complicated problem of making some kind of generic camera class that will work for all games.

To create useful matrices for a camera, the XNA `Matrix` class provides [various methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix_methods.aspx). Like `CreatePerspective` for a Projection matrix, or `CreateLookAt` for a View matrix.

(So, to make a simple camera class, have it take your camera setup information - position, field of view, etc - and output the necessary matrices.)

To use those matrices when drawing, you need to set them on your Effect (where they will be used to transform vertices to their screen positions in your vertex shader). [XNA 4.0 introduces effect interfaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/05/05/effect-interfaces-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx), which provides a consistent interface for doing this.

Comment: Thanks, that does answer my question.